# Android Gtalk API?

Tags: android, google-talk

Long back, android used to have GtalkService that let applications use Gtalk for various purposes, it was removed due to security reasons.
Do we still have a method of invoking a Gtalk service that let us interact with gtalk from another application e.g. pinging a friend programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTalk is nothing else as a Google XMPP Service. So you have 2 options for android:

1. Use [Asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/), a ported Smack Library for Android

or

1. Use [AsmackService](https://github.com/rtreffer/AsmackService) (not yet releases but functional), together with [AsmackLibrary](https://github.com/rtreffer/AsmackLibrary).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [sources of TalkMyPhone application](http://code.google.com/p/talkmyphone/). Don't know if its using GtalkService, but it does gtalk interaction, works nicely for me.